# Multiple bevels with changes in direction?

Tags: bevel

I am completely new to Blender and 3D modeling so I am sure my question has a basic solution.

I am attempting to model conduit for a rocket. The conduit has slightly beveled sides (easy) but then has a slight taper to become more narrow, and then extends further up the rocket - all while continuing the bevel. I have attempted many combinations of loop-cuts and bevels but can only get part of the way there.

Attached is an image of the top-view of what I am attempting.

I will be grateful for any insight.

Thank you,

John
[image]

Comment: so is it like a cylinder with thickness that shrinks? Not sure to understand where is the difficulty...

Comment: Model it in 2D (no wall thickness) and add a solidify modifier.

Comment: I'm sorry the drawing was not more clear. The edges are intended to be flat with a beveled cross-section, and then a step inward as shown in the drawing. 

I did figure out how to so this by manually moving edges, beveling the end, and then extruding the smaller face. Not super precise but close enough for my purposes. 

John